# Creating A visual Graph 

Tags: java, user-interface, graph

I am trying to make a visual graph on java in which each vertex is a 10X10 dot and there can be edges connecting between them, when I press or drag a vertex I want it and its edge to move along the mouse.

How would you suggest to define the vertex? I'm trying to be as effective as I can be with it, for example making each vertex listen to the mouse and check if it was clicked is a bit ineffective.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking about the data structure or about how to represent a data structure in a GUI? You should not confuse both things.

Answer (score 1):

Make your graph view listen for mouse events, and when the user clicks on the graph canvas, ask each vertex whether it contains the point the user clicked on. (You'll need a `hitTest` method for that, or something like that). When one of the vertices signals that it contains the point the user clicked on, you can consider the vertex to be selected.

Comment: thats what i was thinking too

Comment: do you think vertex needs to extend JComponent(paint itself)? or does the graph paints it?

Comment: I would simply make the graph paint it. It could be a separate class with a paint() method or something like that, but I would not derive it from JComponent.

Answer (score 0):

do you have to use your custome-made solution?
Maybe it worth to consider thirdparty solutions for this: Like JUNG or JGraph?